# Modeling a many-to-one tree in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I'm attempting to model an organizational tree in grails. What I have works, but I have a couple of questions about it.

Here's my 'Organization' class:

```
class Organization {

  String title
  Organization parentOrg

  static hasMany = [ childOrg: Organization ]

  static mappedBy = [ 
    childOrg: 'parentOrg',
    parentOrg: 'childOrg'
  ]

  static constraints = {
    parentOrg nullable: true
  }
}
```

Now, when I create a new 'Organization' like this:

```
def newOrg = new Organization(
    title: 'New Organization',
    parentOrg: oldOrg).save()
```

Everything works well, and the relationship to the parent seems modeled correctly.

But if I try to call something like `oldOrg.childOrg.each` I will get no results unless I have also called `oldOrg.addToChildOrg(newOrg)`.

Furthermore, when I check the tables that are generated, the only reference to this relation is the `parent_org_id` column on the `Organization` table.

Now, I realize that this is all that is necessary to also determine the `childOrg` relations, but I don't notice ANY change in the database from before I call `oldOrg.addToChildOrg(newOrg)` to after!

So where is this relation getting stored when I call `addToChildOrg` when I don't see anything change in the database?

Also, how can I have this relation setup to automatically create the `childOrg` relation when I add the `parentOrg`? I don't think I should have to call `addToChildOrg` when I'm adding the `parentOrg`. It should be implied.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use a `hasOne` association to store the foreign key reference in a bidirectional one-to-one.

Since you don't want to add the relationship from other side each time so you can make a setter to ease your work, like-

```
setParentOrg(parentInstance){
   this.parentOrg = parentInstance
   parentInstance.childOrg = this
}
```

Now when you do `organisationInstance.parentOrg = parentInstance`, the setter gets invoked for you, and the relationship is setup the way you want.

Comment: This might help take care of not needing to also call `.addToChildOrg`, but where is this relation being stored in the database? By stating `mappedBy = [childOrg: 'parentOrg']` I get that the childOrg is based on the parentOrg column, but what changes after calling `.addToChildOrg`? Nothing in the database that I can see. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

if I'm correct you're missing **belongsTo** definition, because you need to define that every instance of Organization is owned by its parentOrg instance.

*try this class declaration:*

```
class Organization {

  String title
  Organization parentOrg

  static belongsTo = [parentOrg: Organization]
  static hasMany = [ childOrg: Organization ]
  static mappedBy = [ childOrg: 'parentOrg']

  static constraints = {
    parentOrg nullable: true
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't have any effect either. The only thing persisted to the database is the `Organization` table, along with the `parent_org_id` column. There is no reference to `childOrg` in the database, and the child reference isn't created unless I specify `addToChildOrg()`. Which is also weird, because calling `addToChildOrg()` works, but there's nothing additional added to the database, or no additional area where that information could even be stored!

Comment: I see, so you mean that you cannot find childOrg in database? But by using `static mappedBy = [ childOrg: 'parentOrg']` you told hibernate, that `childOrg` will be mapped by `parent_org_id` and hibernate does load your collection of childOrgs like `SELECT * FROM organization WHERE parent_org_id = :this.id`. **If you want to see them in database**, just remove `mappedBy` and add `joinTable` into the mapping

Comment: Right, but when I create an `Organization` with `parentOrg: oldOrg` the child association doesn't work unless I also call `oldOrg.addToChildOrg(newOrg)`. Shouldn't the addition of the parent imply the child relation? Especially with the `mappedBy`?